# Javascript Month method issue

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to parse a date to `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

**My function:**

```
function formatDate(value) {
  // value = '2016-07-05T00:00:00-04:00'
  var dt = new Date();
  dt = Date.parse(value); // dt = 1467691200000
  return dt.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" +   dt.getFullYear();
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> dt.getMonth is not a function

It seems that `dt` isn't a valid date so I can't access `getMonth()` method. Just not sure what I need in order to get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

`Date.parse()` doesn't returns an object type `Date`, you can check it: `console.log(typeof dt);`.

So, you can do it using [toLocaleDateString](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocaledatestring.asp) method.

Here's is the snippet working:

```js
function formatDate(value) {
  var dt = new Date(value);
  dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() + 1);
  console.log(dt.toLocaleDateString());
}

var dates = ['2016-05-04T00:00:00-04:00', '2013-07-05T00:00:00-02:00', '2015-04-06T00:00:00-01:00'];

for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
  formatDate(dates[i]);
}
```

**Note:** *toLocaleDateString* method uses **your** locale conventions, in other words, it can returns in another format for another user.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass `value` as a parameter when creating the Date, instead of separately calling the parse function.

```
function formatDate(value) {
    var dt = new Date(value);
    return dt.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" +   dt.getFullYear();
}
```